# Изменить каждое число в тексте на заданную величину

Tags: php, html, css, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл стилей. Нужно изменить размер каждого шрифта на заданную величину.

На входе

```
body {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

и тд

На выходе

```
body {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Интернеты пишут, что регулярки не поддерживают арифметические выражения, но 
может есть какая то лазейка...

Comment: регулярки в помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте замену по регулярному выражению с callback-функцией [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$css = <<<CSS
body {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
CSS;

$inc = 2;

 $css = preg_replace_callback(
              "/(font-size:\s*)(?<size>\d+)px/im", 
              function($matches) use ($inc){
                  return $matches[1].($matches['size'] + 2)."px";
              },
              $css
          );

print_r($css);
```

на выходе получите желаемые

```
body {
    font-size: 15px;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Есть, конечно, нюанс, что шрифт может быть задан как `font: 20px Tahoma ;`. Для замены по нескольким маскам можете использовать `preg_replace_callback_array()`

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!!!